# Highlight the character the cursor is on in vim

Tags: linux, vim, cygwin, vimrc

How can I highlight the cursor in `vim`? I am interested in highlighting only the letter that the cursor is in.
Using:

```
set cursorcolumn  
highlight CursorColumn guibg=lightblue ctermbg=lightgray
```

Highlights the entire column and I want only the character that the cursor is on to be highlighted

Comment: The character under the cursor is already highlighted… by the cursor itself. What more do you want?

Comment: @romainl:I used the cursorline and the line is highlighted in a lightgray color.If I add the above snippet I get a cross.I want the instead the character under the cursor to get this color

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CursorColumn` is irrelevant, what you need to define is `Cursor`, preferably with a background color different from `CursorLines`'s background color.

Supposing your `Cursorline` has a dark gray background:

```
highlight CursorLine guibg=#303030
```

You can have a slightly lighter `Cursor`:

```
highlight Cursor guibg=#626262
```

Vim's behavior *may* be different in a terminal emulator, though. As an example, whatever I do with `cterm` or `ctermbg`, I can't make it look how I want in Gnome terminal: it's always in reverse video. Which makes it perfectly outstanding, actually. In rxvt-unicode, the background color of the cursor is always the one defined in `~/.Xdefaults`, which can be whatever you want.

Comment: I pasted the `highlight CursorLine guibg=#303030` (after I commented my definitions) and all I see is that the current line is underlined. Additionally in your answer you don't define a `Cursor` although you mention that this is what I need.

Comment: Tried `highlight Cursor guibg=#626262` but does not do anything.

Comment: That was a typo. Fixed. Do you use Vim in a terminal? GVim? That line in my answer will only work in GVim. I explained in the last paragraph that you won't get the result you want in a terminal emulator.

Comment: I use `vim` in cygwin. So cygwin is a terminal emulator?Ok I will try it in a linux as soon as I can

Comment: I don't know Cygwin. You use GVim if you have menus like "Tools" or "Syntax" or if the output of `:echo has('gui_running')` is `1`. If you use Vim in a terminal emulator you must configure that terminal emulator so that it uses a color that works for you.

Answer (score 3):

switch to terminal mode

```
:ter
```

and then switch back to edit/ view mode.

```
exit
```

Automatically the cursor will be highlighted.